# how to unwind from SkView

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Hi I have a segues from the main menu UIViewController to start playing the game I created. But if i want to exit back to main menu there is no prepareForSegue function in SpriteKit.

How can I unwind back to the main menu from my scene?

I am using touches began to handle events instead of UIButtons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have call `performSegue` from the `ViewController` containing the `SKView` not the SKScene. Create a weak variable inside `SKScene` pointing to the `GameViewController`. Set it when the SKScene is created. Then call performSegue on this property.

```
//Game Scene
class GameScene {
   weak var gameViewController : GameViewController?
}

// GameViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //Other code
    scene.gameViewController = self
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

When you want to perform the segue inside GameScene, call

```
 // Inside GameScene
 self.gameViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("indentifer", sender: self)
```

To go back the the main view.

```
self.gameViewController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I keep getting 'GameScene' does not have member named performSegueWithIdentifier

Also wont this create viewController over ViewController? dont I need an unwind segue so that im not just created new viewControllers on top of each other? @rakeshbs

Comment: sorry. i made a mistake in the last statement. i edited my answer. you should call self.gameView.Controller. performSegue

Comment: this works but I am creating new views on top of each other rather than unwinding. The app eventually crashes and performance drastically reduces the FPS. Is there a way to create an exit segue

Comment: that doesn't seem to work....

only had self.gameViewController?.popoverPresentationController 
available

Comment: try this if you are using a navigation controller.        `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`